# If conditions are met for TRUE response copy row to new sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this formula that give me an occasional TRUE when the value in a cell of Sheet1 Col A  matches the value of a cell in Sheet2 Col A.

```
=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A:$A,1,0),"")<>"","TRUE","")
```

Is it possible to copy the true response and the value of Col A to Sheet3?

I have this info on sheet 1:

```
ColA          ColB
username1     Datapoint1
username2     Datapoint2
```

On Sheet 2 I have a list of approved usernames.

If username1 is on sheet 2 Col C on sheet 1 would show TRUE because of my VLOOKUP formula. In an ideal world in addition to showing TRUE it would add a row on sheet3 and insert the values of Col A and Col B.

This would indicate that on sheet 2 Username4 exists, resulting in a TRUE:

[image: This would indicate that on sheet 2 Username4 exists, resulting in a TRUE]

Comment: Add a cell reference on Sheet 3 to the cells on Sheet 1? I might be missing something...can you provide some sample data, what your spreadsheet looks like?

Comment: Is the value of these comparisons unique? I suggest you provide a sample about your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this arrary formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!A$1:A$10,Sheet2!A$1:B$10)>0,ROW(Sheet2!A$1:A$10),1000),ROW(A1)))&""
```

Enter this formula in Sheet3 A1 and end **with STHIF+CTRL+ENTER**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**If the issue is,** "Is it possible to copy the True response and the value of Col A to Sheet3?"

Then you can try below written *array Formula* in in Cell B2 of Sheet3, since I'm assuming that Column A has User Name.

```
{=IF(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A2:C7,{1,3},FALSE)=0,"",VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A2:C7,{1,3},FALSE))}
```

**Note,**

1. After you finish the formula in B2, select cell B2 & C2, press F2
   and finish the formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.
2. Fill the formula down, for row 5 you get UserName4 & TURE.
3. If required, please adjust the data Range.

*Check the Screen Shot:*

[image]